# The brake pedal goes down to the floor after replacing the rear rotors and pads on my 2010 highlander

Tags: brakes, highlander

I have replaced rear brake pads and rotors on my 2010 highlander and right after I went to take the car for the test drive the brake pedal goes all the way to the floor. There is no leak anywhere. I scanned the car and it says ABS inlet valve coil Left circuit and gave me C1201 code and I was wondering if someone can help me with it. Could the ABS sensor cause the brake pedal to go all the way down to the floor and if not what else could it be other than the master?

---

I did not touch the bleeders and no air in The system and the boots are fine.I did a lot of brake jobs and this never happened to me before. The car was fine till I did the brakes and I just did the brake job Luke always and nothing else and I'm hoping its not the master. Any ideas what it could be??

Comment: Ya I have checked and there is enough fluid, so you do not think it could be the sensor that cause the pedal to go down?

Comment: And what else could it be other then the master?

Answer (score 3):

Did you just try to pump the brakes up several times? When you compress the caliper, this leaves a gap between the brake pads and the rotor. If it didn't, it would be very hard to get the new pads/caliper back onto the rotor. So, when you first get behind the wheel, you need to pump the brakes several times to get the caliper piston to the point it is pushing the pad against the rotor. After several pumps, it should bring firmness back to the pedal.

Comment: Yes I did more then a few times and its not working and the pedal still goes to the floor. Could the ABS sensor cause this cause I got C1202 code when I scanned it

Comment: Yes I did but did not help, could the ABS sensor cause this cause I got C1201 code when I scanned the car

Comment: Did you double check to ensure you have enough fluid in the master? A code is an indication of *something* being wrong, not the cause of a problem. I'm seeing conflicting reports on the error code. as far as it goes, clear the code and see if it comes back. Sources suggest the C1201 code could set when other codes are set.

Answer (score 1):

Did you open the bleeders for any reason?  Have you tried bleeding the brakes?  Are you sure there's no tear in the caliper boot?  If they worked fine before the brake job, it would have to be something that happened during the procedure.  ABS sensor seems unlikely to be the cause of your problem.  Most likely air in the brake lines.

Answer (score 0):

Hei,

I had the same problem after changing the brake pads. I used many days to figure out why. Actually, it is the caliper piston rubber seal worn out. When you pushed the brake pedal the caller piston pushed outward, but when you released the pedal, the piston retracted. So you need to change the square rubber ring seal to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you explain why the pedal went to the floor?  This expanaton does not seem related to me.

Comment: lili is absolutely correct despite the negative flag! Exactly correct!!! I spent freakin ages trying to work this out ! I Never let air in - the damn square cut seal in the calipers were stuffed after I retracted the pistons!!! Either rebuild calipers or replace calipers then bleed - all fixed!